# Hello! How can get the height for an element after ajax pass the data to the element: $("#contents").html(data) $("#contents").height()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, height, after-effects

I have search on stackoverflow and i have found many answers for that but all is wrong so. I now i need to pass first the data to the element and then call the height function, but is still not working after the data has html on the element.

```
$.ajax({
    url: el.attr("data-action"),
    dataType: "html",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        var id = el.attr('data-modal');

        $("body").append("<div id='" + id + "' class='modal'><div class='modal-contents'>" + data + "</div></div>");

        var modal = $("#" + id);

        contents = modal.find(".modal-contents").first();

        alert(contents.height());

        modal.addClass("visible");

        contents.slideDown("slow");

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .ajaxComplete() to be sure the Element is complete loaded(sorry for bad english)

try this:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, request, settings ) {
    var modal = $('#YOUR_ID'),
    contents = modal.find(".modal-contents").first();
    alert(contents.height());
});
```

Comment: inside ajax function or outside?

Comment: what is in your alert output? Is there any Error in your console?

Comment: so it's working :) you have to open your Modal in ajaxComplete. If it will stay closed or hidden, your modal has a height = 0

Comment: mark as answered please :) And an upvoted would be nyze too :) thanks